# Compact space T2 satisfies first axiom of countability

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a compact space $T_2$ that, for all $x \in X$, exists $\mathcal{U}_x \subseteq \tau$ countable that satisfies $\bigcap \mathcal{U}_x = \{x\}$. Prove that $(X,\tau)$ satisfies the first axiom of countability.

I'm stuck in that problem because I don't know how I find the countable base of $x$.

Comment: The sense is what follows: $\mathcal{U}_x$ is a countable family of neighbourhoods of $x$, not a countable set. Try now to find a countable base of neighbourhoods of $x$.

Comment: I already see that but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in a compact $T_2$-space the following statement holds: If $A\subset X$ is closed and $O\supset A$ is open, then there is $U\subset X$ open with $A\subset U \subset \overline U\subset O$.

$\{x\}$ is closed in $X$, thus for each $O\in\mathcal U_x$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ with $\overline U\subset O$. Choose such a $U$ for each $O\in \mathcal U_x$. The collection of those $U$ is countable. Now let $B_x$ be the collection of all finite intersections of those $U$. Then $B_x$ is still countable and $\bigcap_{U\in B_x}\overline U = \{x\}$.

We show that $B_x$ is a neighborhood-basis for $x$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Assume that for each $U\in B_x$ we have $\emptyset \neq U\setminus V\subset \overline U\cap V^c$. Then $\{\overline U\cap V^c: U\in B_x\}$ has the finite intersection property. By compactness $V^c\cap \bigcap_{U\in B_x}\overline U = V^c\cap \{x\}$ is nonempty. This contradicts $x\in V$.